# If condition, assigning wrong values in python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements, integrate

Update :

Checked the suggested solutions, didn't work. However narrowed down on the problem. So posting that below if people can shed some light.

```
def X_he_z3(z):
    flag = -1 
    if z <=3.0 :  # z<3
        #x_he=1.
        flag = 1

    else:      
        flag = 0 
        #print flag
    if flag == 0 :
        X_he_z3.Xe_He_II = 1.
    else :
        X_he_z3.Xe_He_II = 0.
    return flag
```

Running :

```
z = np.linspace(0,6,1000)
s = 1000
X  = []
X2 = []
f = []
one = np.ones(s)
for i in z:
    f.append(X_he_z3(i)) # Returns flag
    X.append(X_he_z3.Xe_He_II)

plt.plot(z,X,'*') # He_II
```

[image]

```
plt.plot(z,f,'*',c='g')
```

[image]
 Flag has proper values in `[0]` and `[1]` range. So I guess the problem is how this flag values are called into the variables creates some confusion. Any suggestions ?

---

**Original Question**

This is my code, the function `X_he_z(z)` is called for integration. 
Inside the function, there is a if condition. under it there is a representation of a step function. if `z < 3 ==> X_he_z.Xe_He_II = 0.` `else` `if z > 3 ==> X_he_z.Xe_He_II = 1.`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def X_he_z(z):
    global omega_m
    omega_m = 0.3
    global Y;global x_he;#global Xe_He_II;global Xe_He_III;
    Y = 0.25

    X_he_z.x_h = 1.  # X_e_H ~ 1 for z<6 
    if (z - 3.0) < 0.00 :  # z<3
        #x_he=1.
        X_he_z.Xe_He_II = 0. # ** This is the line in question**
        X_he_z.Xe_He_III= 1.
        x_he = (X_he_z.Xe_He_II + 2.*X_he_z.Xe_He_III)

    elif (z - 3.0) > 0.00:       
        X_he_z.Xe_He_II = 1. # ** This is the line in question**
        X_he_z.Xe_He_III= 0.
        x_he = (X_he_z.Xe_He_II + 2.*X_he_z.Xe_He_III)

    #print 'z = %s, X_He_III = %.2f'%(z,Xe_He_III)
    X_he_z.x_he  =x_he
    X_z = ((1.-Y)*X_he_z.x_h + (1./4.)*(Y)*x_he)
    X_he_z.fe=X_z

    Num = X_he_z.fe*(1.+z)
    Den = (omega_m*((1.+z)**3.)+(1.-omega_m))**(0.5)
    I = Num/Den
    X_he_z.G = [I,X_he_z.fe,X_he_z.Xe_He_II,X_he_z.Xe_He_III,X_he_z.x_h,X_he_z.x_he]
    #print G
    #print I
    return I 

# Running the code + Integration

z = np.linspace(0,6,500)
s = 500
Dm = []
X  = []
one = np.ones(s)
for i in z:
    #print 'z ',i
    t = X_he_z(i)
    Dm.append(integrate.quad(X_he_z,0,i))
    X.append(X_he_z.G)
    # Returns in order : 
    # I, fe, He_II, He_III, H, He

Dm = pd.DataFrame(Dm,columns=['DM','Int_error']) 
Dm['z'] = z
Dm['H']= pd.DataFrame(X)[4]
Dm['He']= pd.DataFrame(X)[5]
Dm['HeII']= pd.DataFrame(X)[2]
Dm['HeIII']= pd.DataFrame(X)[3]
Dm['fe']= pd.DataFrame(X)[1]
```

The rest of the part is not necessary for this post. I would expect the 
 `X_he_z.Xe_He_II` value to have a step function , like the attached plot (ignore the `Y-axis` values), 
[image: How I expect the He_II to behave in the z-range as x-axis]How I expect the `He_II` to behave in the `z-range` as `x-axis`

But instead if I look into the values, I see this is how the values are :
[image: The black marked dots in the lower right are a surprise to me and I can't understand how.]
The black circled dots in the lower right are a surprise to me and I can't understand how.

The corresponding values are as a result wrong, going into the integration call. I need a fix for those few points in the bottom.

The results can be also checked on the output file :

[image]
If we checked the the `line 444,` we will see the 3rd column which is the z value and `z > 3 (= 5.3146)` and the `6th` columns is for `He_II`, which should be `1` as it falls in the else condition in the code above, however it gives `0` meaning it is in the first case i.e. if block. Why is this happening ?

Comment: What Is supposed happen if z == 3.0? (Add an else to the if-elif and see what it catches)

Comment: I thought about that, however in higher float values, nothing is exact 3.000000 . so they will either be < or > 3.00000 or higher accuracy.

Comment: Your assumption may be correct, but It is in the nature of assumptions that they may be wrong, and it only takes a couple of lines of code to test it. Or change < to <=, or > to >=

Comment: And those tests are the only alternative paths through your code. The edge of Occam’s razor is gleaming at you In the sunlight: this is the simplest explanation for what you are seeing and should be eliminated before looking for more complex and far more unlikely causes like a problem with multiplication/addition.

Comment: Just checked, by  putting <= and >= , getting same results

Comment: Windows x64 using Python 3.7.2 64-bit: I get two occasions (out of 213566 calls to 'X_he_z()') when z==3.0, one when G= [0.5587808731418688, 0.8125, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0] and one when G= [0.7854885306184621, 0.875, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0]. Go figure. Why on earth would you cross your fingers and assume that because z is very unlikely to be exactly equal to 3 that it in fact never will be equal to 3, when a) that's patently a silly assumption, and b) it's incredibly easy to ensure it never comes true: replace the `elif` with `else`. Or maybe there is some glitch in whatever Python 2.x you are using.

Comment: Credit where it's due - well done for posting a [mre].

Comment: Works perfectly for me on cPython 3.7.2 on Windows, i.e. clean plot with step function at 3.0. What versions are you using, and on what OS? And what type of Python - is it cPython?

Comment: Python : 2.7.16. Mac Mojave. Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 1):

Change the `elif ...:` line to `else:` and you won't see the problem you created any more.

Comment: Maybe thjere are two problems, but this completely fixes the two z==3.0 I see. If you add an else: after the if<0 and elif >0, for you is the else ever taken?

Comment: Hi, Please check the original post. I have posted an update.